# Datastream stream failed with error: Binlog is configured incorrectly on the source database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-datastream

I launched a [Datastream](https://cloud.google.com/datastream) stream on GCP with a MySQL database as the source, but the stream failed with the following error:

> "Binlog is configured incorrectly on the source database."

How can I fix this? Is there something wrong with my source database?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Datastream public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/diagnose-issues#mysql_errors) this happens for MySQL sources if the binlog configuration on the source is incorrect. Perform the following actions:

1. Verify that binlog is [configured correctly](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-mysql-database).
2. Confirm that the binary log format of the MySQL database is set to ROW.
3. Restart the stream.